# Multiple set comprehension in a functional style

Tags: functional-programming

Does any one know of a function/idiom (in any language) that takes a set and returns two or more subsets, determined by one or more predicates?

It is easy to do this in an imperative style e.g:

```
a = b = []

for x in range(10):
    if even(x):
        a.append(x)
    else:
        b.append(x)
```

or slightly better:

```
[even(x) and a.append(x) or b.append(x) for x in range(10)]
```

Since a set comprehension returns a single list based upon a single predicate (and it effectively just a map) I think there ought to be something that splits the input into 2 or more *bins* based on either a binary predicate or multiple predicates.

The neatest syntax I can come up with is:

```
>> def partition(iterable, *functions):
>>    return [filter(f,iterable) for f in functions]
>> partition(range(10), lambda x: bool(x%2), lambda x: x == 2)
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for [`(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` on Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5ba%5d+-%3E+%28%5ba%5d,+%5ba%5d%29) yields [`Data.List.partition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:partition).

> The `partition` function takes a predicate a list and returns the pair of lists of elements which do and do not satisfy the predicate, respectively; i.e.,
>
> ```
> partition p xs == (filter p xs, filter (not . p) xs)
> ```

If you look at its source and translate to Python,

```
def partition(predicate, sequence):
    def select((yes, no), value):
        if predicate(value):
            return (yes + [value], no)
        else:
            return (yes, no + [value])
    return reduce(select, sequence, ([], []))
```

which is pretty nicely functional.  Unlike the original, it's not lazy, but that's a bit trickier to pull off in Python.

Comment: Aha, I forgot Hoogle allowed searches based on type signature! My curiosity has been satisfied, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `Enumerable` mixin has a [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001496) method that does what you describe.

Comment: That's fairly close to what I was looking for. I think a nicer way of doing it might be to allow multiple functions to be passed in though.